# Could not print out entity id in twig from many to one proxy entity

Tags: symfony, proxy, doctrine, entity

I hope someone could help me, maybe this is a bug or there is solution for it..

I have a job entity which has ManyToOne relation to client entity.

```
class Job {
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
 */
protected $client;}
```

When I get client from controller

```
$client = $job->getClient();
// I could get client id here in controller, but could not render in twig template
$clientId = $client->getId(); 
return $this->render('client' => $client);
```

and render it in template

```
{{ client.id|default('0') }}
```

It always output 0,

but all other properties of client entity can output properly.

```
{{ client.name }}   ----> this can print out properly, except {{ client.id }}
```

and I use Netbeans debug windows, I saw this client entity is a proxy entity, and it's __isInitialized__ value is 0, if I set:

```
$real_client = $em->getRepository('AceCoreBundle:Client')->find(4);
```

this is real entity and can output client id in twig.

Even I have a proxy entity with __isInitialized__ value is 1, it also can output the id value of the entity in twig.

Not sure what 's wrong with it..

Because of this problem, every time I have to render 'client_id' => $clientId separately to twig

```
return $this->render(array('client_id' => $clientId, 'client' => $client));


{{ client_id|default('0') }}  // in twig
```

is there anyway I can convert proxy entity to real entity?

Part of My Client entity code as below:

Client.php

```
// doctrine
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class Client {

    const STATUS_NEW = 0; // new client
    const STATUS_APPROVED = 1;  // client approved by accounting team

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */

    public $id;

    /*
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     *
      //protected $user; */

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Contact")
      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="primary_contact_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $primaryContact;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contact", mappedBy="client")
     */
    protected $contacts;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Acme\QuoteBundle\Entity\Costing", mappedBy="client")
     */
    protected $costings;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Acme\JobBundle\Entity\Job", mappedBy="client")
     */
    protected $jobs;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="display_name",length=150,unique=true)
     */
    protected $displayName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="delivery_addr",type="text",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deliveryAddr;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=200, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $suburb;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=4, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = "0",
     *      max = "4",
     *      minMessage = "",
     *      maxMessage = "The postcode cannot be longer than than {{ limit }} characters length"
     * )
     */
    protected $postcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="courier_post_aid", type="integer")
     */
    protected $courierPostAid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="invoice_addr",type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $invoiceAddr;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\Staff")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_manager", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $accountManager;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean",name="is_reseller", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $isReseller;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deletedAt;

/**
 * CONSTRUCTER OF CLASS
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->contacts = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->status = $this::STATUS_NEW;
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    $this->isReseller = false;
    $this->courierPostAid = 0;
}
```

Part of Job Entity code:

Job.php

```
// doctrine
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\JobBundle\Repository\JobRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="job")
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class Job {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="prev_job_id")
     */
    private $prevJobId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\Category")
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="job_num",length=20)
     */
    protected $jobNum;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="prev_job_num",length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $prevJobNum;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="costing_num",length=20)
     */
    protected $costingNum;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\Client", inversedBy="jobs")
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="contact_id",type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $contactId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=50, name="contact_firstname")
     */
    protected $contactFirstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=50, name="contact_lastname", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $contactLastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name",length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="special_instruction", type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     */
    protected $specialInstruction;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_in", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $dateIn;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_out", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $dateOut;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\Staff")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_manager", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $accountManager;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="job_data", type="array")
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     */
    protected $jobData;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\Staff")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id") 
     */
    protected $createdBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="modified_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $modifiedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\Staff")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modified_by", referencedColumnName="id") 
     */
    protected $modifiedBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deletedAt;

    // CONSTRUCTION
    public function __construct() {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->dateIn = new \DateTime();
        $this->prevJobId = 0;
    }
```

JobController.php

```
public function editAction($id) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $job = $em->getRepository('AcmeJobBundle:Job')->find($id);



        if (!$job) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find job entity.');
        }



        $client = $job->getClient();

        return array(
            'client' => $client,
        );
        }
```

edit.html.twig

```
<input type=hidden id="client-id" value="{{ client.id }}" name="client_id">
```

I tried to use NetBeans to debug it, I found that when I change app/cache/dev/classes.php , about line 4867, in function getAttribute, I add some code below

```
// if I add this change to , it can print out id properly...
                    if ($item == 'id') {
                        return $object->getId();
                    }
```

before:

```
 return $object->$item;
```

Then I can print out the id attribute in twig..

[image: Netbean debug windows]

Comment: This is definately weird, I don't believe it is a problem about a proxy entity or like that. It is weird that you can get all the properties except the id... check the real value of the id in your database. What error message do you get if you don't put the filter |default? If you just write {{ client.id }} do you get an error?

Comment: If I don't put default value, it doesn't have any error message, it just print out empty value.like <input type=hidden id="client-id" value="{{ client.id }}" name="client_id">,  it will print out <input type=hidden id="client-id" value="" name="client_id">

Comment: I have posted part of the codes at the end of the question. Please have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that this is due to doctrine lazy loading the client entity. You should try switching your controller's doctrine call to a repository method with a join query on clients (don't forget to use paginator if needed). Or switch the default fetch mode on your entity (I don't remember exacts steps for this).

Still a weird error, please post your client entity code for better assist.

Comment: Did you mean using QueryBuilder to left join Client TABLE? Like below:
`
$qb = $em->getRepository('AcmeJobBundle:Job')->createQueryBuilder('obj');;
        
 
        $qb->select('obj');
       

        $qb->leftJoin('obj.client', 'c');
        $qb->where('obj.id = '. $id);

        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        
        $job = $query->getSingleResult();
`

I tried to print out `<input type=hidden id="client-id" value="{{ job.client.id }}" name="client_id">`  it still print out empty value, no error display. just a empty value.

Thanks.

Comment: I changed symfony's cache file classess.php , it worked.. please see the end of my question above...